# Can we import SQL bacpac file in existing DB (azure)

Tags: azure, backup, bacpac

can we create a new bacpac file without creating a new DB in azure

I tried creating it in the existing DB.
It didn't work , a new DB is being created.
I want the bacpac on the existing DB............................................

Comment: Bacpac files are for ms sql server or their azure equivalent, not for mysql.

Comment: Could you please provide which is you are using wither SQL server or my SQL server?

Comment: AFAIK, Azure SQL Database doesn't support import a BACPAC file into an existing database.

Answer (score 0):

.bacpac files are created for the entire database and MS SQL Server does not allow to selectively import data or schema from a .bacpac file into an existing database

- > If you are trying to import , and a new database is being created there might be name mismatch otherwise it gives DB already exist with same name error